# Can my ISP find out if my wireless is protected or not?

Tags: wireless-router, isp

Im just wondering how much my ISP knows about my activities. I have a Modem from them this modem then connects to a SITCOM wireless router which then leads to MY PC's, Phones, Laptops. I really need to know if my ISP knows if my router is in unprotected state of wireless or not. The Sitcom box it not theirs, we payed for it long after getting this internet. Does my Sitcom wireless router send data to my ISP on its own, indicating delicate information such as wireless protection on or off? Or does the ISP's modem fish out this information on its own since our wireless router is connected to it?

Would greatly appreciate any answer.

Comment: I'd guess that there's probably no simple way for the ISP to tell if your router is protected or not (other than logging on, if you foolishly left it with the factory password), but you'd be a fool to NOT at least require a password to use the router.  "Unauthorized" use of routers can include criminal activities, and if I were on the jury I'd hold you liable for damages due to such activities, if you did not take at least minimal precautions to protect the router.

Comment: (BTW, why do you care if the ISP can tell this or not?  No ISP in their right mind would prohibit protecting your LAN, and you're a fool to not protect it.)

Answer (score 0):

The ISP can monitor all of your information unless it is encrypted. Your router's password is only to keep people from logging into your network and stealing your information (so you should be more worried about your neighbors and the people around you). If your ISP suspects something, they can monitor your traffic all they want.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP doesn't know jack about your LAN.  As far as your ISP is concerned, they assign your modem an IP and are done with it.  What you have behind it is up to you.  That's not to say they can't monitor traffic leaving and entering your modem.

This is the whole wonderfulness of [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).  The router does all the work of deciding what goes where on the LAN.  Your ISP could only be aware of the information as it traverses the modem, beyond which it has wiped its hands clean.

**Your ISP does not know if your wireless router has its wireless security turned on.**

**Your Wireless Router does not talk to your ISP.**

Be aware, there are some nutty things that can be accomplished when digging deep into network traffic.  However, this would require a human being very interested and motivated.

Answer (score 0):

ISPs can only see as far as their equipment and what they can see is dependent on the equipment.  In your case, your ISP can only "see" the modem.  As for what they can see, most likely its nothing, other than what the modem provides them, such as line-levels, and other information that is really just used for troubleshooting connectivity.  As for your wireless router, since it is connected to the modem, they *may* be able to see that it exists and they *may* be able to determine manufacturer and model, but thats it.  Your wireless router does ***not*** transfer information to the ISP.  It doesnt know who your ISP is.  It doesnt even know if it is even connected to the internet.